# VS Code not showing proper TypeScript types for function - why?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Here's my function definition:

[image]

Here's why I try to use it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong in my function definition that TypeScript is refusing to recognize the possibility of returning `null`?

Comment: Do you have [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) (or [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict)) enabled in your TS compiler options?

Comment: @VLAZ I did not. I only had a "target" (es2017) and "outDir" (dist). N other values were set. I added "strict: true" and now it's working